# Code signing failed for imported framework - on distribute app

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

After updating to xCode 10, I can no longer export .ipa file for Enterprise distribution. The reported errors are connected with the imported .framework, code signing and i386 architecture. When I click on distribute app > Enterprise, and wait for some time for App Thinning, this error occurs:

[image]

Show logs:

> description = "Failed to verify bitcode in
>   xxxx.framework/xxxx:\nerror: Cannot extract bundle from
>   /var/folders/tz/gwpqvzg14wng25bs5m2pk4xw0000gn/T/IDEDistributionOptionThinning.JcG/Payload/xxxx.app/Frameworks/xxxx.framework/xxxx
>   (i386)\n\n";

Or if we skip Thinning and proceed to exporting, we have this error:

[image]

Comment: Did you find the reason or some solution for this?

Comment: This framework was imported manually (as it is not available on CocoaPod) and was added to embedded binaries. After removing the framework from embedded binaries and adding local path to pod:

    pod 'TheNameOfTheSDK', :path => 'TheRootOfTheProject/Resources/LibFolder'

and installing pods, everything worked. Not sure it is general solution for the problem. Think in other cases you will need to contact the developer of the SDK.